# Switch layout by CapsLock and do nothing by Shift+CapsLock

Tags: unity, 11.10, keyboard-layout, capslock

I need switch keyboard layout by <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.
I did `System Settings` -> `Keyboard layout` -> `options` -> `keys to change layout` -> `caps lock` and it works.

But sometimes I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and I get angry, so I want to block <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to have upper case. How can I achieve this? I tried to select `System Settings` -> `Keyboard layout` -> `options` -> `Caps Lock behavior`-> `disable Caps Lock`, but after that <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> doesn't change layout, as I want.

OS is Ubuntu 11.10

What should I do to achieve this?

**Started bounty**

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? What is Shift+Caps Lock supposed to do? What does it do now?

Comment: @daniel: now it works as CapsLock[Before I make CapsLock to switch layout](IT IS WIRTTEN AFTER i PRESS sHIFT+cAPSlOCK). But I want to make it do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your best option would probably be to disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key combination by mapping it to doing nothing. That way every time you mistakenly type it does nothing. I haven't tried it but [here](https://superuser.com/questions/2194/remap-keys-in-linux)'s something that might help.

After a few trials, I can recommend the following alternatives:
1. Set your "Key(s) to change layout" to "Caps Lock (to first Layout), Shift+Caps Lock (to last Layout)" and put your 2 languages in the correct order so that your <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> changes and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> changes back. (However I'm assuming this won't do either since you mistakenly press Shift+Caps Lock)
2. Set your "Key(s) to change layout" to "Shift+Caps Lock" instead. At least this way you're more conscious of your error.

Hope I helped.

Comment: making CapsLock and Sift+CapsLock to change layout sounds great but didn't work on my PC. I will try first way(map to do nothing), thank you

Comment: It took me a few seconds to realise what it does. Hitting "Caps Lock" stays in the language you're currently on (probabably the default one). So to change the language the first time you need to do "Shift+Caps Lock" and "Caps Lock" to change back. I'm sure you tried both, but since I got stuck I thought of mentioning it.

Comment: I tried check both CapsLock and Shift+CapsLock to change layout, but after that CapsLock doesn't change it. I'll try to make Shift+CapsLock do notning by other way, throught

Comment: No you mustn't set them both. If you do, it picks whichever was checked last. At least that's what it seemed like when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = "
xmodmap -e "clear Lock"
```

Not sure if its permanent though.